# ErrorChannel is not filled within different steps

Tags: spring-integration

I know this is a question wich is asked quite often but my problem seems to be a little bit different.

Short introduction:
I have an DMLC which is polled against a queue.
After that the message is send via DirectChannel to a *chain*.
Within the *chain* I use a *unmarshalling-transformer* (transform the incoming xml to interface-object).
Then again different steps (Validation etc., all via DirectChannel) and at the end of the flow I want to insert the (transformed) message into a database.

In the flow below there are different "error sources". For example the input message isn't proper and couldn't transformed (unmarshal) into an object. Or the database could not be achieved to insert the record.

Now the question concerning the different error types:
If the input message could not be transformed or the validation of the data generates an error, i want to send an error-message (or the exception) to the **error-channel** because it doesn't make sense to rollback the message.
If the database-insert fails (maybe due to a "system hang") I want to **rollback** the message to the input queue (peInputQueue).

Enclosed a snipplet from the config-xml:

```
    <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="peMessageDrivenAdapter"
                                        channel="jmsHeaderEnricherChannel"
                                        acknowledge="transacted"
                                        connection-factory="jmsTransactionConnectionFactory"
                                        concurrent-consumers="1"
                                        max-concurrent-consumers="5"
                                        max-messages-per-task="5"
                                        receive-timeout="500"
                                        auto-startup="true"
                                        destination="peInputQueue" />

   <int:chain id="jmsInputChain" input-channel="jmsHeaderEnricherChannel" output-channel="routerTransformChannel">
       <int:header-enricher>
           <int:priority value="#{T(de.axa.batch.ecmcm.cmab.util.CmabConstants).LOW_PRIO}"/>
           <int:header name="countMessage" ref="counter" />
           <int:header name="protocol" value="jms"/>
           <int:header name="msgReceiveDate" expression="T(System).currentTimeMillis()" />
           <int:error-channel ref="errorChannel"/>
       </int:header-enricher>
       <int-xml:unmarshalling-transformer id="jmsModelUnmarshallerTransformer"  unmarshaller="jmsModelUnmarshaller"/>
   </int:chain>

    <int:header-value-router input-channel="routerTransformChannel" header-name="protocol">
        <int:mapping value="jms" channel="jmsTransformToCoreChannel"/>
    </int:header-value-router>

    <int:transformer id="jmsToCoreTransformer" input-channel="jmsTransformToCoreChannel"
                     ref="cmabInboundQueueMapper" output-channel="validationChannel"/>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="validationChannel"
                           output-channel="processChannel"
                           ref="validationBean" />

    <int:service-activator input-channel="processChannel" ref="databaseProcess"/>
```

In the configuration above the message is rollbacked if per example "validationBean" throws an exception.
But this is **not** what I'm expected. I want to adjust the message into the error channel. Therefore I enhanced the header in the "header-enricher" (see chain-element) to an errorChannel. 
In the "validationBean" I recognized the errorChannel within the MessageHeaders but unfortunately it doesn't work.
Instead of this a rollback is initiated. :-(

So how can I achieved (my) desired solution.

Any helps are really appreciate.
Kind regards,
Bodo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. That `error-channel` header isn't reachable. Just because everything is in the same Thread, so, an exception is just thrown like it is with regular Java.
2. The exception gets caught in the `ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.GatewayDelegate`.
3. And since there is no `error-channel` according to your configuration it is re-thrown to the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` to make rallback.

So, you should make an `error-channel` configuration on the `<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` and also you should add some `ErrorHandler` to sever the "rallback or not" logic.

Comment: Hi Artem, thank you very much for help!
I follow your point 3 and it works perferctly with an own ErrorHandler. :-)
Kind regards, Bodo

Comment: Glad to hear! The good tone would be to accept the answer :-)